# react-native firebase how to remove specific nodes by id?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to remove a node by an id in a firebase realtime database but I can't find any documentation on it. I've looked in the basic docs here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data

but the sub-heading on deleting just says to use the remove() method? I'm not sure how to do this if I only want to remove one of several children of a node?

here is my current attempt:

```
deleteNotes = noteId => {
    const uId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    console.log("logging note id", noteId);
    let userRef = firebase.database().ref('Users/'+uId+'/Notes');  //where all a users notes are stored
    userRef.remove().then(()=>{
      console.log("successfully removed reference")
    })
  };
```

should I do something like userRef.child(id).remove() or some similar chain? all my pushed notes have their own id given to them as a key value pair, but do I need to do something else to generate keys for them in a firebase realtime database?

pointing me to a good reference doc would also be awesome if possible.

**thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `remove()` on a reference to the exact path you want to remove. So if you want to delete `/Users/uid123/Notes`, you can do any of these:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/uid123/Notes').remove();
firebase.database().ref('Users').child('uid123').child('Notes').remove();
firebase.database().ref('Users').child('uid123/Notes').remove();
```

---

If you want to remove one specific note, that'd become:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/uid123/Notes/idOfTheNote').remove();
```

---

If you want to remove a few notes but leave others, you can use a multi-location update:

```
var updates = {};
updates['idOfTheNote1'] = null;
updates['idOfTheNote2'] = null;
firebase.database().ref('Users/uid123/Notes').update(updates);
```